# Cosmological expansion as the internal optics of a bubble

Tags: cosmology, curvature, cosmological-inflation

Consider a Flatland universe bubble with a hole as a disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $R$, with the hole being mapped to the boundary. The bubble can be thought as the Riemann sphere with the hole of radius $1/R$ around the north pole. If we imagine cosmology in this plane geometry, points at finite distances will look toward asymptotically farther regions as having increasingly larger spatial scales. If light waves would propagate across regular Euclidean plane, objects far away would look increasingly redshifted to observers placed near the origin.

> **Question:** How would flatland cosmologists physically distinguish a Riemann sphere spacetime cosmology from a flatland inflationary
> cosmology?

Comment: I do not think they would be red shifted . Why would a photon lose energy in flat space ? photons do not "read" spatial scales".

Comment: @anna in this hypothetical flatland, photons travel across the Euclidean plane. Consider it just an analytical exercise into understand what contradictions or inconsistencies would arise

Comment: I cannot see how the photon would lose energy in a euclean inertial frame.

Comment: @anna the sources exist in the Riemann sphere, but once they emit light the photon propagates thru Euclidean plane

Comment: You are proposing a redshift. redshift means change of energy of photon, this cannot happen in euclidean space

Comment: @anna, when the photon is produced close to north pole of the Riemann sphere, the characteristic scale is much larger on the Euclidean plane. When that radiation propagates toward the south pole, the wavelength seems much larger compared with the corresponding structures nearby

Comment: It *seems* to the observer. The photon cannot observe, it just follows the space time line. In a non general relativity space how can it loose energy and go towards the infrared,